# How get only value cookie

Tags: java, android, cookies

I need to get only the value cookie and no name, no domain and no path.

[image]

How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
 List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    cookie=cookies.get(i).toString();
                    //System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                    System.out.println("- " + cookie);


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `toString()` to `getValue()`. Since, `toString()` is `Cookie` class object representation in readable form.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) 
{
   cookie=cookies.get(i).getValue();
   System.out.println("Value : " + cookie);
}
```

If you are interested for specific cookie value then, you could compare cookie name in the same loop.

```
if(cookies.get(i).getName().equal(<<cookie name>>))
{

    cookie=cookies.get(i).getValue();
    System.out.println("Value : " + cookie);

}
```